# How to show controls button in windows phone 8.1 map control

Tags: maps, windows-phone-8.1

Basically I want to show built in controls button like zoom in or zoom out etc in my windows phone 8.1 map control
Like this type of in google maps. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

This my map code

```
   <Maps:MapControl MapServiceToken="abcdef-abcdefghijklmno" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" x:Name="MapControl" >
        <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapIcons">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding picture}" Width="50" Height="50"   ></Image>
                        <TextBlock Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="Black"  FontSize="15"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl>
  </Maps:MapControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just show it above the map, something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Maps:MapControl ...
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button> ...
        <Button> ...
        <Button> ...
    </StackPanel>
</Grid
```

Comment: Then I have to write code also for that Is there any builtin functionality?